Get Push notification title using SQL Marketing Cloud
I'm trying to get push notification title using SQL but I only found body on existing dataviews , does someone knows how can I get it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
